# Unable to use Truffle Migrate with Kovan

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to use Truffle for the first time to deploy and test my new Smart Contract.  I can deploy and test it in Remix just fine, but the truffle migrate command fails with the following error:

**Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"Migrations" -- Invalid chain id..**

This is using my Kovan node on QuikNode, which is also working fine from my node js app.  Here is the truffle-config.js settings related to the wallet:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const mnemonic = "twelve word seed phrase that im not dumb enough to put here"

networks: {
    kovan: {
      provider: function() { return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://my.node_url.here/") },
      network_id: 42       // Kovans's id
   }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out.  Looks like the newer version of hdwallet-provider really wanted me to use the name parameter syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by the "name parameter syntax"? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: What I mean is rather than using HDWallerProvider(mnemonic, url, .. ) etc, use:
HDWalletProvider(
 mnemonic: "my phrase",
 providerOrUrl: "my_url",
 .. ) etc

More information here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

Comment: Steady.
Got the same error still.
Could you please write in more detail how you fix it?
Thanks.